# My progress isn't syncing to WoT

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I have an issue where my progress isn't syncing to World of Trucks. It only shows I did two jobs when I did plenty of jobs. Not even showing my truck either. I own two trucks, one of the IA driver uses the second one. In game, it shows all my progress lot higher than what's in WoT. I don't do quick jobs. I do hauls from companies.

Comment: It will only show progress of "external" contracts/market jobs, not regular ones. Quick jobs as well as regular ones are carried out offline. As for why your trucks aren't in sync, I don't know.